# Access p5.js functions and properties on an object, instead of in the global scope?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

There are tons of p5.js variables, and they are all defined globally, which can seriously clutter the global scope. Is there a way to store them in a single object, like this:

```
const p5 = [something goes here]
p5.setup
p5.draw
p5.preload
p5.color
p5.fill
p5.stroke
// instead of
setup
draw
preload
// ...etc
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the significance of nesting the p5 library functions within an object. Could you elaborate a little more on that?

Comment: [This page](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/p5) of reference have you covered.

Comment: Oh nice, that's some good info @Ricky Mo.

Comment: @RickyMo That's what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the usage pattern for p5.js called [instance mode](https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html). In this mode you create an instance of the [`p5` object](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/p5) with a callback that defines your sketch.

Additionally, if you are using TypeScript and/or compiling a Node.js package as a bundle or module for use in the browser than you can use the npm packages [p5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p5) and [@types/p5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/p5) so that you can import/require p5 as a module and if you are using TypeScript get type checking.

Comment: Yep, that's what I wanted. Marked it as correct. Someone answered this in the comments.